# Angular 4 http get request failing

Tags: angular, http

I am running an Angular 4.x app and have a GET request to an endpoint that has querystring parameters such as the following :

`https://dev.mywebsite.com/debug/me/user?__token=1000001445.k4mv42stmo1h7x1&apiversion=1&appid=3apiversion=1&appid=3`

This works when I add this into postman and I can get a response back however when I run the following code in my Angular component it fails and gives the following error(s)

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://dev.website.com/debug/me/user', {
        params: { token:'1000001445.k4mv42stmo1h7x1', appid:3 }
    })
        .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data', data);
    });
}
```

In the console.log in the network tab I can see this request has `[object Object]` under the the Headers tab in the Querystring section - why is this?

Comment: Not quite familiar with Angular 4 myself but don't you need to set params using `HttpParams` class (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)?

Comment: you should call the `get` by passing in `https://dev.mywebsite.com/debug/me/user?__token=1000001445.k4mv42stmo1h7x1&apiversion=1&appid=3apiversion=1&appid=3`. without params.

Comment: From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#options), params can be of type `HttpParams | {[param: string]: string | string[];};` so what you have is valid except the values should be strings `appid: '3'`. This will generate a url of `https://dev.website.com/debug/me/user?token=1000001445.k4mv42stmo1h7x1&appId=3`. From the url you posted, it looks like you are missing some fields from your params object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

    this.http.get('https://dev.website.com/debug/me/user',
       { params: new HttpParams()
    .set('token', '1000001445.k4mv42stmo1h7x1')
    .set('appid', '3') }).subscribe....
```

If need be, do some logging on your back end to ensure it is receiving the correct parameters and returning the right data.